# React: Dropdown value to text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Starting to try and learn React from vanilla HTML, I'm not really understanding the linking of certain objects and events with Arrays.

Basically I want to have a dropdown that the user can select an option, and then have that dropdown fill some textfields with certain values from inside the array.

In this case, Textfield 1 reads the filetype, textfield 2 reads the bitdepth

Current code is below. Note, using spectrum components so sp-picker instead of dropdown

I don't know how to get the Handler to read anything other than the event and likely this code is totally the wrong way to do this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const SaveOptions = () => {

    //Default Options HOOKS

    const [filetype, setFileType] = useState("TIFF");
    const [textfieldValue, setTextfieldValue] = useState("16");

    //ARRAY

    const filetypeOptionsArray = [
        { name: "TIFF", extention: "TIFF", bitdepth: "16" },
        { name: "PSD", extention: "PSD", bitdepth: "16" },
        { name: "JPG", extention: "JPG", bitdepth: "8" },
    ]

    // Handlers

    const handleFiletypeChange = (e) => {

        setFileType(e.target.value);
        setTextfieldValue(e.target.value);

    };

    return (

        <div style={{ border: "1px solid #555", padding: "5px", borderRadius: "5px" }}>

            <div className="row" >
                <sp-picker size="s" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <sp-menu slot="options" onClick={handleFiletypeChange}>
                        {
                            filetypeOptionsArray.map((e) => {
                                return <sp-menu-item selected={filetype === e.value ? true : null} key={e.name} value={e.name}>{e.name}</sp-menu-item>
                            })
                        }
                    </sp-menu>
                </sp-picker>

            </div>

            <sp-textfield value={filetype}></sp-textfield>
            <sp-textfield value={textfieldValue}></sp-textfield>

        </div>
    );
}

export default SaveOptions;
```

Comment: Why are you attaching to the onClick event instead of the onChange event ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to do. Most of your code is right except for you attaching the `onChange` function to the `onClick` property instead of the `onChange` property

I've attached a basic example below because you used custom html elements in your code that I don't have access to.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    name: "Jason Bourne",
    age: 32,
  },
  {
    name: "Steve Wang",
    age: 19,
  },
];

function App() {
  const [option, setOption] = React.useState(null);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const onChange = (ev) => {
    const val = ev.target.value;
    setOption(val);

    const person = people[val];
    if (person) {
      setText(person.name + " is " + person.age);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={option} onChange={onChange}>
        {people.map((person, index) => (
          <option value={index} key={index}>
            {person.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(ev) => setText(ev.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to feed the Array "filetypeOptionsArray" into the onChange function so that it can access properties like { name: "TIFF", extension: "TIFF", bitdepth: "16" }?

I'm using the onClick currently because the spectrum dropdown doesn't respond to onChange

Comment: I've updated the answer above so you can try it out and see if that's what you need. You can't use javascript objects as values for html elements but something you can do instead is use the index of the item as the value. That way after someone changes the value you can access the item again using the index. Another option might be if each item in the array has a unique id or something, use that as the value and find it in the array using the id.